# Javascript if statement not executing code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, if-statement

I have a pretty simple code that checks if the items in an array are contained in another. If they are, I push into the `itens` array an input checked checkbox, if they are not, I push a regular unchecked checkbox to the array. Check it out:

```js
$.ajax({
  url: '${pageContext.request.contextPath}/filial/select.json',
  method: 'GET'
}).done(function(json) {
  var itens=[];
  var filiaisSelecionadas = ${filiais};
  for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
    if(filiaisSelecionadas.includes(json[i])) {
   itens.push('<input id= "idFilial'+json[i][0]+'" type = checkbox class=checkbox1 name = filiaisId value="'+json[i][0]+'" checked>' +json[i][1]+"-"+ json[i][2]  + '</input></br>');
 } else {
      itens.push('<input id= "idFilial'+json[i][0]+'" type = checkbox class=checkbox1 name = filiaisId value="'+json[i][0]+'">' +json[i][1]+"-"+ json[i][2]  + '</input></br>');
 }
  }
  $('#idFilial').html($("<tbody/>", {html:itens}));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

But for some reason the code inside the `if(filiaisSelecionadas.includes(json[i]))` just doesn't execute. The treatment works just fine. If the item isn't in the array it pushes the unchecked checkbox. However if the item IS in the array, it just doesn't execute? I would understand if it always executed the else statement, but not executing neither???? This confuses de b'jesus out of me...

Edit: The `filiaisSelecionadas` (that gets filled with the `${filiais}` EL)is an array of an object that has a bunch of properties. The Json returned is an array of the same objects, but doesn't contain the same exact objects as the other. The json array is always either bigger or the same size as `filiaisSelecionadas`.

Edit 2: By request of user Hongarc I added `console.log()` to if and else, the result is as follows:

```js
$.ajax({
  url: '${pageContext.request.contextPath}/filial/select.json',
  method: 'GET'
 }).done(function(json) {
  var itens=[];
  var filiaisSelecionadas = ${filiais};
  for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
   if(filiaisSelecionadas.includes(json[i])){
    console.log("The IF statement is executing!");
    itens.push('<input id= "idFilial'+json[i][0]+'" type = checkbox class=checkbox1 name = filiaisId value="'+json[i][0]+'">' +json[i][1]+"-"+ json[i][2]  + '</input></br>');
   }
   else{
    console.log("The ELSE statement is executing!\"");
    itens.push('<input id= "idFilial'+json[i][0]+'" type = checkbox class=checkbox1 name = filiaisId value="'+json[i][0]+'">' +json[i][1]+"-"+ json[i][2]  + '</input></br>');
   }
  }
   $('#idFilial').html($("<tbody/>", {html:itens}));

  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

with the output being
[two lines of "The ELSE statement is executing!"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aw5q5.png)

Mind that my json array has size 4 and for the test I made it so it would hold 2 objects that are in the other array and 2 that aren't. So the espected output should have been "The IF statement is executing!" x2 and  "The ELSE statement is executing!" x2.

Comment: How is the `json` response looking and what is `filiaisSelecionadas`?

Comment: Replace the `itens.push` lines with different `console.log`s to rule out that part.

Comment: `filiaisSelecionadas.includes(json[i]` make sure that filiaisSelecionads is array of strings and json[i] is string literal.

Comment: *"The Json returned is an array of the same objects"* – This is most likely not the case since the JSON is returned by an AJAX request. They may be the same objects on the back-end, they may look the same when parsed in the JS, but they're two different entities in the memory which is why the check is always false.

Comment: Can you please fix all the obvious problems in your question that you have stated repeatedly aren't the problem in comments on answers? for example, `url: '${pageContext.request.contextPath}/filial/select.json',`, `var filiaisSelecionadas = ${filiais};`, etc. If you're using something that replaces that content with real content, stick fake information there for your question so that you have valid javascript. ${foobar} actually means something in javascript when used in a template literal, so leaving it in place is at best confusing.

Comment: If statements aren't magic, they evaluate what you provide them. If they're going to the else when you expected it to go to the former, then you  haven't provided what you think you have. Log it and compare your expectations to what is actually happening. Remove the ajax request from the equation if you have to.

Answer (score -1):

Your loop is not iterable because `json.length` will return undefined

“Object.keys()” and then try to find the length.

Comment: *"The treatment works just fine. If the item isn't in the array it pushes the unchecked checkbox. However..."*

Comment: Sadly thats not it... The loop executes fine, but the code inside the IF statement doesn't...

Answer (score -1):

I think the `includes()` method checks if a value is inside an array, but if you have an array inside it won`t return true. It only works if you store references to variables.

so for

```
let var1 = [1, 2]
let values = [var1, [1,2], 'primitive']
values.includes('primitive') // true
values.includes(var1) // true
values.includes([1,2]) // false
```

You need to work out another way of checking if it is contained in the array.

You could use `.filter()` or `.find()` array functions. Check them out on the [Mdn docs (Array filter)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)
I can't help you out unless you reveal more of the underlying structure, but I'm sure you can figure it out.

Hope it helps.